# Что означает интструкция ret(il код)

Tags: c#, дизассемблирование

Имеется такая строчка в методе на il: "IL_0007:  ret". Что это значит ?
(Понятно, что это связано с окончанием метода, но как конкретно)

Comment: `ret` это `return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IL многое почерпнул из набора инструкций 8086. `RET` означает return, то есть возврат из метода.

Вызов процедур и возврат на низком уровне реализован с помощью *стека*. Инструкция `CALL` сохраняет в стеке адрес инструкции, которая следует сразу за ней и передаёт управление туда, куда вы ей указали.

Когда процессор встречает инструкцию `RET`, он извлекает из стека адрес *следующей инструкции* и передаёт управление на неё. Из-за того, что адрес возврата хранится не в регистрах, а в стеке, размер которого достаточно большой, процедуры могут вызывать друг друга столько раз, сколько потребуется.

Впрочем, если вы допустили ошибку в программе, или запустили рекурсивную функцию на очень больших данных, стек всё-таки может оказаться переполненным. Именно ошибка переполнения стека — stack overflow — дала название этому сайту, где мы задаём и отвечаем на вопросы.

Comment: `IL многое почерпнул из набора инструкций 8086` - думаю, если бы автор вопроса был знаком с ассемблером x86, то вопроса бы не возникло)